i18next with multiple loadPath (node.js)
I having a trouble with i18next for my node.js/express app.
Currently, I just have ONE loadPath (/locales/).
But, my project consist of many of features that decoupled by folders.
So, I want to have multiple loadPath.
For instance, '../customer/locales', '../sales/locales', '../order/locales'
Is there any solutions for this?
Thanks in advance.
// My current code is looks like this

const path = require('path')
const i18next = require('i18next')
const Backend = require('i18next-fs-backend')


const language = generalConfig?.locale || 'en-US'

i18next
.use(Backend)
.init({
    debug: true,
    initImmediate: false,
    fallbackLng: 'en-US',
    lng: language,
    load: 'currentOnly',
    ...

    backend: {
        loadPath: path.join(__dirname, '../../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json')
    }
})


module.exports = i18next

